# Customize object/element name with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, resttemplate, jaxb2, jackson2

I'm very new to JAXB, so I'm having trouble cracking this (I assume) very simple use case.

I have a set of schemas I got. I have no control over those, I cannot change them. In these schemas, I have declarations such as

```
<xs:complexType name="CustomerType">
    ...
```

I try to generate classes from these. So such a declaration becomes

```
@XmlType(name = "CustomerType", propOrder = {
    "field1",
    "field2"
})
public class CustomerType {
    ...
```

Then I need to use this class to create XML messages using a RestTemplate. The problem is, the object in the XML message is not supposed to be "CustomerType", it's supposed to be just "Customer". Like I said, I cannot edit the schemas. I also cannot directly edit the generated sources. I need some kind of external customization that tells either the source generating process, or the marshalling process, how to transform the names of the objects. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bindings to customize class or property names. Typically you'll have a file like `bindings.xjb` like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:customType[@name='CustomerType']">
            <jaxb:class name="Customer"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:customType[@name='CustomerType']//xsd:element[@name='field1']">
            <jaxb:property name="f1"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

There are quite a few things you can customize with bindings (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)), but certainly not everything.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see a way to customize the name of the root object with an external binding file (not just the class, but the name that will be used for mashalling, which is in @XmlType annotation the name attribute).

Comment: Are you sure you must change `@XmlType` for this? This is doable, but I doubt Jackson really takes `@XmlType`.

Comment: I worded that incorrectly. What I meant is I need to change the value that is defined by the @XmlType. I actually cannot change the annotation itself, because it's in a generated source. That's why I'm looking for a way to do it in with an external file somehow.

Comment: @Sethiel Well, you might have worded it incorrectly, but now it's worded as it is worded and this is the answer.

Comment: @Sethiel I can show you how to modify `@XmlType` using [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin), but first let's get this question done. Accept the answer, ask another question.

Comment: @Sethiel In the new question provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I seriously doubt that `@XmlType` influences Jackson marshalling - so you may very well be solving a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This is why an MCVE is needed here. You may very well not need to modify `@XmlType` at all.

Answer (score -1):

The way DTO objects are created is:

You define all the types at one place like: CustomerType, UserType, OrderType and so on.

You then create another schema and import appropriates XSD's within where you have defined multiple types. Then you actually use/aggregate     these type definitions to create your XML Schema for objects .       Something like below

```
<xs:complexType name="CustomerOrders">
<xs:element name="Customer" type="CustomerType">
<xs:attribute name="Orders" type="OrderType">
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting. Also, I have exactly one xsd file for request and one file for response for every service.

Comment: You must have another Wrapper ComplexType that wraps the CustomerType Object. As you mentioned you have an XSD each for your Request and Response object then your Request object must have an xs:element which has the type as CustomerType. Is it possible for you to share your Request XSD ?

Comment: I don't think I can share the XSD. But yes, I do have another wrapper complexType. Something like

`<xs:complexType name="individualType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="individual-name" type="individual-nameType"/>

    <xs:element name="date-of-birth" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>`

This is in the same file, which I cannot edit. Now I need these objects to be translated to "individual" and "individual-name". What exactly are you suggesting I do?

Comment: As evident here individual-name, date-of-birth are the child of individualType object and hence can be used by getting an instance of individualType object. You need to search the XSD to find is there any complexType that wraps the individualType.

Comment: OK, turns out I was so clueless I was asking the wrong question. So, let me ask from scratch: How can I change the name the **root** complexType will be marshalled to, without changing the schema or adding any annotations to the generated code?

Comment: You cannot do that as everything is tightly governed by the XSD definition and that's the whole notion behind having XSD. Imagine someone on the other side receiving the marshalled XML (with your modified names) but using the same XSD as yours. That side will be completely clueless.

Comment: @piy26 *You cannot do that* - this is not correct. Generated code can be customized with bindings to a great degree.